# How to add Spyder icon to my favorites in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04, anaconda

I have installed Spyder through Anaconda. I want the Spyder icon in my favorites in Ubuntu 18.04. How can I add it?

Answer (score -1):

Find the desktop entry with `locate spyder.desktop` and follow this [steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/1026532).